# A* search (non goal with 0 heuristic)

Tags: graph, a-star, heuristics

I have a graph and i need to apply A* algorithm on it. but this graph has a non goal with heuristic value 0. I am now confused if this is correct. Is it possible to have a non goal with heuristic value 0?

Answer (score 2):

To take an extreme case, what happens if *every* node has a heuristic value of 0? In that case, you'll expand out nodes in increasing order of distance, and you essentially now have Dijkstra's algorithm instead of A* search.

It's always safe to have a heuristic value of 0 at a node in A* search, since the heuristic just has to underestimate the distance to the goal. Lower heuristic values cause A* to run longer, and higher (but still admissible) values make the algorithm take less time to find the goal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's fine.  As long as the heuristic is [admissible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic), A* will work.

However, your heuristic will not be [consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_heuristic).  This means that that the algorithm may run slower than you'd probably expect, because it may need to expand the same node multiple times.